# Will this system radiate energy or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

[image]

Consider a current-carrying ring as shown, having no resistance. Now, we can say that the fields around this would be constant. Thus, we must expect this system not to radiate energy. Considering it in another manner, the charges present inside are moving on a curved path with drift velocity. Their motion is thus accelerated and so we must expect them to radiate energy. With both ideas contradicting each other, which one is correct?

Comment: Check out these supercool things called SQUID: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID